# string.to_f precision issue when the value trailed by two zeros

Tags: ruby

I get input string `"400.00"` and need to display `400.00`.

**Expected float_value** :`400.00`

I used `to_f` to do the task since `to_i` will return `400` alone. The code is

```
x="400.00"
float_value=x.to_f
```

But in this case, I am getting the output as `400.0` which is not acceptable for my case.

**current float_value** :`400.0`

Both are equal and have no difference, but its not for any calculation purpose, its for some other display purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for fomatting:

```
sprintf("%.2f", 400)
#=> "400.00"
```

Comment: @Pavan I don't think so, the OP prints the output using `puts`

Comment: OP can directly print the data without any fanciness I think. Why *string* to *float*, if finally need a string.

Comment: @sam Yes your *googly* actually was a *bouncer* to us.. Next time be specific.